# Can a packed C structure and function be ported to java?

Tags: java, c, android-studio

In the past I have written code which handles incoming data from a serial port. The data has a fixed format. 
Now I want to migrate this code to java (android). However, I see many obstacles.

The actual code is more complex, but I have a simplified version here:

```
#define byte unsigned char
#define word unsigned short

#pragma pack(1);
struct addr_t
{
  byte foo;
  word bar;
};
#pragma pack();


bool RxData( byte val )
{
  static byte buffer[20];
  static int  idx = 0;

  buffer[idx++] = val;

  return ( idx == sizeof(addr_t) );
}
```

The RxData function is called everytime a byte is received. When the complete chunk of data is in, it returns true.

Some of the obstacles:

The used data types are not available to java. In other threads it is recommended to use larger datatypes, but in this case this is not a workable solution.

The size of the structure is in this case exactly 3 bytes. That's also why the #pragma statement is important. Otherwise the C compiler might "optimize" it for memory use, with a different size as a result.

Java also doesn't have a sizeof function and I have found no alternative for this kind of situation.

I could replace the 'sizeof' with a fixed value of 3, but that would be very bad practice IMO.

Is it at all possible to write such a code in java? Or is it wiser to try to add native c source into Android Studio?

Comment: Can't you use `native` and a JNI? Might be overkill, but worth looking at. At least then you keep the C code intact. Otherwise use a `byte[3]` in Java. And a nicely worded question. Not sure about the downvote. By the way the size of `unsigned short` varies from platform to platform.

Comment: Java primitive data types have a fixed size that should not depend on the platform, so hardcoding the values should not be a problem. You can simply write a deserialize function that takes a ByteInputStream then reads the appropriate number of bytes into your fields.

Comment: When you call `RxData()` more than 20 times it will raise a buffer overflow.

Comment: Your'e right. I simplified it a bit too much. In the real thing It would do something when all expected bytes are in, and also make the idx variable back to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C code has its problems too. Technically, you do not know how big a `char` and a `short` is. You probably want `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` respectively. Also, I'm not sure how portable packing is.

In Java, you need a class. The class might as well tell you how many bytes you need to initialise it.

```
class Addr
{
    private byte foo;
    private short bar;
    public final static int bufferBytes = 3;

    public int getUnsignedFoo()
    {
        return (int)foo & 0xff;
    }
    public int getUnsignedBar()
    {
        return (int)bar & 0xffff;
    }
}
```

Probably a class for the buffer too although there may already be a suitable class in the standard library.

```
class Buffer
{
    private final static int maxSize = 20;

    private byte[] bytes = new byte[maxSize];
    private int idx = 0;
    private bool rxData(byte b)
    {
        bytes[idx++] = b;
        return idx == Addr.bufferBytes;
    }
}
```

To answer the question about the hardcodedness of the 3, this is actually the better way to do it because your the specification of your protocol should say "one byte for foo and two bytes for bar" not "a packed C struct with a char and a short in it". One way to deserialise the buffer is like this:

```
 public class Addr
 {
     // All the stuff from above
     public Addr(byte[] buffer)
     {
         foo = buffer[0];
         bar = someFunctionThatGetsTheEndiannessRight(buffer[1], buffer[2]);
     }
 }
```

TI have left the way bar is calculated deliberately vague because it depends on your platform as much as anything. You can do it simply with bit shifts e.g.

```
    (((short)buffer[1] & 0xff) << 8) | ((short)buffer[2] & 0xff)
```

However, there are better options available. For example, you can use a [java.nio.ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) which has the machinery to cope with endian isssues.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a neat solution. Although I still don't like the fixed value of 3, but there might not be another way.  Another thing though: in my C code the next step would be something like addr_t* ptr = (addr_t*) buffer;  Then I would have a handy structure to work with, which will be automatically filled, without having to assign each of its members separately.

Comment: I thought that might be the next step, but it's quite a bad way to do it. You're trusting that the endianness of your machine is the same as the protocol.